# Firebase ID token is not generating after SSL Pinning enabled

Tags: android, firebase, ssl, firebase-authentication

Firebase ID token is not generating after SSL Pinning enabled. Please help me find the solution of this problem.

SSL Pinning Code

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Firebase Code(**FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR**)

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {                           
                            return;
                        }
                        try {
                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();                            
                        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add system certificate also i.e **src="system"**

```
    <base-config>
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
                <certificates src="system"/>
            </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
```